# Mobile version not showing on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design

This site: http://hashsupport.com/demo/experlogix/
changes to the mobile version at 640px width, it does it in the browser fine.
But on mobile devices, it does not show the mobile version, it only shows the desktop version, shrunk to fit the smartphones.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific which devices are affected? Works fine for me (on iOS 7).

Comment: You probably are missing user-scalable meta: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />